# Wrong application provided to open in the Intent chooser when I need only map applications

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, android-activity

I've got several problems.
I have a task to provide different map applications to a user when he pushes a button.
I do it by creating an **Intent.createChooser**. Everything works fine until the user install application "Zoom" for online meeting. And it's literally not what user expects to see in the dialog of apps and obviously he can't use it as map application.
I create an **Uri** with coordinates, put it to the Intent with *ACTION_VIEW*. Like this:

```
val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=53.9000,27.5667"))
```

Then i create **Intent chooser**:

```
val chooser = Intent.createChooser(mapIntent, "Build a route with:")
```

And then I start **Activity** with chooser: `startActivity(chooser)`
And then I get a wrong app "Zoom" in this dialog:
[WRONG DIALOG SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZxFn.jpg)

**The first question is:**
Maybe there are some ways to see how actually Zoom App appears in this dialog and why my Intent receives this app activity?

The second problem is a case how I try to solve the first one. So I tried to use **queryIntentActivities** for my Map **Intent** and see in Log what activities are suitable for my **Intent**. It should return me a list of all activities that Intent chooser shows me, but in fact it returns me only one! activity MapsActivity:

```
val pm: PackageManager = packageManager
            val activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(mapIntent, MATCH_ALL) //or MATCH_BY_DEFAULT, no difference
            activityList.forEach {
                Log.d("ACTIVITY MAP", it.toString())
            }
```

And in Log it shows next info:

```
D/ACTIVITY MAP: ResolveInfo{6c40733com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity m=0x208000}
```

Only one MapsActivity is shown... Where is the others **Activities** that shown to me in the **Intent chooser**?

Comment: I found that Zoom App appears in Dialog because it has the JoinByURLActivity which is okay for my Intent with ACTION_VIEW and Uri as a parameter. But in Zoom case the Uri is the link for the online video meeting. Maybe any way to deprecate this activity for using in my app? Or maybe I should change my Intent?

Comment: AFAIK, there's nothing you can do about it and I think that you might be loosing really precious time on things that you cannot control. What happens there is that zoom declares that it can handle a location intent (probably because you can add a location for a meeting) and the system matches your app with it. Just ignore it and add better features for your users.

Comment: @IulianPopescu  I found that Zoom App appears in Dialog because it has the JoinByURLActivity which is okay for my Intent with ACTION_VIEW and Uri as a parameter. But in Zoom case the Uri is the link for the online video meeting. Maybe any way to deprecate this activity for using in my app?

Comment: As I said, I don't think it's worth the time (or even possible). You can target for specific app, but then you won't have the dialog picker anymore. See how it works with Google maps https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents